# Calculating over different rows with constraints in R

Tags: r, if-statement

This is how my data looks like:

```
       1    2        3    
1  20.47039  xae 20.65273
2  21.94899  xei 22.06170
3  22.96345  p 23.06622
4  23.61655  xei 23.68949
5  24.50835  p 24.57134
6  25.92349  xa 26.01042
7  26.34687  no 26.44185
8  27.83433  xoe 27.93414
```

I want to calculate now the difference between the time tmin in line 2 and tmax in line 1. 
I managed to do so with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  difference[i] = (VP3_erw[i+1,1]) - (VP3_erw[i, 3])
}
```

However, whenever in column `p` is written, I want to calculate the

```
difference[i] = (data[i+1,1]) - (data[i, 3]) - (data([p,3]) - datadata([p,1]))
```

`p` stands here for the line where `p` is indexed

I tried to work around with `charmatch`:

```
p= c("p")  
ind_p = (as.numeric(row.names(data)) & charmatch((substr(as.character(data[,2]),1,1)), p, nomatch = FALSE) > 0)
```

than trying to bring this in an if -loop:

```
if (ind_p == "FALSE") {
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {  
    difference[i] = (VP3_erw[i+1,1]) - (VP3_erw[i, 3])
  }
else {
  difference[i] = (data[i+1,1]) - (data[i, 3]) - (data([p,3]) - datadata([p,1]))
}
}
```

but I do have problems with indexing to the line where `p` was written and with the if - loop.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be off because there were a few points where I tried to reuse your code but it wasn't reproducible. So, assuming that the name of your dataset is "data" (I didn't use anything named VP3_erw):

```
data <- structure(list(`1` = c(20.47039, 21.94899, 22.96345, 23.61655, 
24.50835, 25.92349, 26.34687, 27.83433), `2` = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("no", "p", "xa", "xae", 
"xei", "xoe"), class = "factor"), `3` = c(20.65273, 22.0617, 
23.06622, 23.68949, 24.57134, 26.01042, 26.44185, 27.93414)), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))

difference <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {

   if (data[i,2] == "p") {
       difference[i] = data[i+1,1] - data[i, 3] - data[i,3] - data[i,1]
   }
   else {
       difference[i] = data[i+1,1] - data[i, 3]
   }

}
```

Comment: Dear Harrison Jones, thank you very much for your help. The code works fine for producing the right distance if no "p" is indexed, but not if data [i, 2] == p. In the example, the distance from xei in row 4 to xei in row 2 should be data[4,1] - data[2,3]. Thank you so much for any help